# Should I use smart contract for storing huge data and real-time updates?

Tags: storage, database

**Scenario :**
Lets say I have DApp on ethereum which has two parties or two types of users
, User A will update his status (uptime or storage or ip address...etc).
User B will be able to browse a marketplace of all these users(A) with their status.

1. There will be thousands of users and thousands of updates per hour , so it will cost a lot of gas for setting values and storage usage for these values , **How to solve this issue ? should I use centralized databases here that I have control of ? or should I use a smart contract that will write to external databases ?  what is the best practice for this issue ?**
2. If I concern for the speed of the status updates ,then using smart contract is not a good solution because every update for a status means triggeing a transaction so it needs mining which depends on how much fees you pay ....**am I right ?**

Comment: Currently is not on your best interest to store large amount of data in a smart contract in the blockchain. CryptoKitties clogged the network for several weeks with lots of transactions and small amount of data. A common approach is to use a store like IPFS and a smart contract to handle updates in batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you end needing storing lot of data in smart contract, it means you don't understand what it is made for.

Storing data in a smart contract is crazy expensive in gas because you change the EVM state "a lot".

If you really have to store data, do it in a database or you can use decentralized storage (IFPS, Swarm for exampe).

Note: If I understand well, you are trying to make a marketplace. What is the point doing it on blockchain? In your case, only transaction should be stored on the blockchain. In consequence, blockchain should be used only as a "tool" for your product, instead of using it as your core tech. (in my opinion)

Edit; to answer your questions:

- 1: Yes, making tons of tx will cost you ton of gas, so ton of ether.
  You could use a private chain or (as said above), reconsider the
  purpose of blockchain for your product.
- 2: Yes, blockchain is slow. arround 13 to 17 seconds for a block to
  be mined (or 2/3 seconds for a fresh private/permissionned chain). So arround this time for a tx to be processed (if you have
  "normal" gas price). You wanna be processed faster? Pay more!

Comment: so the best solution for real time updates will be in external database ?

Comment: Yesm in my opinion